# how to located element using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to find an element which is a button called select.

[image]

what I have is :

```
select_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tri_mat-button-base')  
select_button[1].click()
```

but it does not do what it suppose to. Any one can help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the image as HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this-

```
select_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(class(),'tri_mat-button-base')]")

select_button.click()
```

Looking at your HTML it looks like class name is huge and you are using some part of it thats why use contains and try. If this isn't working then pls paste DOM not as image for more accurate answer.

Comment: `tri_mat-button-base`